# Dados retornados em requisição Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho esse Ajax que pega o retorno de um script PHP. Para isso, dei um "echo" no php e ele me retornou o dado. Se eu quiser trabalhar com mais de um dado, terei que criar um ajax para cada campo? Por exemplo: coloco o crachá em um campo e com ajax encontro o nome do funcionário no campo e preencho o input logo abaixo. Mas se quisesse botar a data de admissão também, tem como? 
Segue AJAX

```js
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
 }

 /**
  * Função para enviar os dados
  */
 function getDados() {

     // Declaração de Variáveis
     var nome   = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
     var result = document.getElementById("content"); //DIV DE RETORNO
     var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

     // Exibe a imagem de progresso
     //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
     document.getElementById("nomefunc").value = 'Pesquisando...';

     // Iniciar uma requisição
     xmlreq.open("GET", "processa.php?txtnome=" + nome, true);

     // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de ado
     xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){

         // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
         if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

             // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
             if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                 if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                 document.getElementById("nomefunc").value = 'NÃO ENCONTRADO!';
                 }else{
                 document.getElementById("nomefunc").value = xmlreq.responseText; //UNICO CAMPO QUE ABASTECE COM O ECHO DA VARIAVEL
                 }
             }else{
                 result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
             }
         }
     };
     xmlreq.send(null);
 }
```

código php

```js
<?php

include 'config.php';

// Recebe variavel do index
    $cracha = $_GET["txtnome"];

//Inicia a consulta ao banco Oracle, com os dados informados pelo cliente.
$consulta2 = OCIParse($ora_conexao,"select
       CRACHA,
       NOME,
       DIA
FROM PCN_CRACHAS
WHERE CRACHA = '$cracha'
ORDER BY 1");

//aqui prepara a consulta, nome da coluna e a variavel retorno da consulta
OCIDefineByName($consulta2,"CRACHA",$v_cracha);
OCIDefineByName($consulta2,"NOME",$v_nome);
OCIDefineByName($consulta2,"DIA",$v_data);
// executa a consulta
OCIExecute($consulta2);

// Atribui o código HTML para montar uma tabela
 while (OCIFetch($consulta2)){
     echo $v_nome;  //Essa retorna no ajax sem problemas
    // echo $v_data; //Se dou echo nessa, o resultado aparece no mesmo campo, junto com o nome
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando usas o método `GET` os parâmetros são passados pelo URL como tens agora:

```
"processa.php?txtnome=" + nome
```

a parte depois do `?` é onde tens os dados. Essa parte extra `?chave=valor` chama-se querystring e podes juntar mais *N* dados separando com `&`. Ou seja se quiseres juntar mais um parametro podes fazer algo assim:

```
"processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
```

#### No lado do servidor

Para passares dados para o lado do cliente podes fazer assim no PHP:

```
 // Atribui o código HTML para montar uma tabela
 while (OCIFetch($consulta2)){
     $array = array('nome'=>$v_nome, 'data'=>$v_data, 'cracha'=>$v_cracha);
     echo json_encode($array);
 }
```

e no JavaScript precisas de fazer parse desse JSON assim por exemplo:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
alert(dados.nome);
alert(dados.data);
```

Comment: Entendi. Mas como faço para identificar uma variável e outra no xmlreq.responseText ? Aqui ele me retorna o valor no meu input la: document.getElementById("nomefunc").value = xmlreq.responseText;

Comment: @Diego como assim? O `xmlreq.responseText` tem o que o servidor enviou. o que recebes do servidor? Como é o teu PHP?

Comment: É justamente isso. No PHP, faço a consulta, retornam 3 variaveis. Para o Ajax "pegar" o retorno, dou um echo em um delas. Quando dou echo nas duas, o resultado sai um ao lado do outro. De alguma forma, precisaria que o Ajax entendesse que a variavel retornada do banco $nome vai para tal campo e a $admissao vai para outro, na mesma div. Qualquer coisa posto um exemplo e passo o acesso...

Comment: Coloca o código do PHP na pergunta que eu junto isso na minha resposta. No fundo tens de fazer um array no PHP com as variáveis e fazer `echo json_encode` dessa variável.

Comment: Coloquei o código agora...Obrigado!

Comment: @Diego juntei mais info à resposta.

Comment: Estou tentando aplicar o retorno nos campos, mas agora no ajax ele entra no "Pesquisando..." e para. Usando o Array que vc mostrou, como posso atribuir o retorno para o input que eu quero no index? Fiz assim:                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                   document.getElementById("nomefunc").value = dados.nome;
                   document.getElementById("nomefunc2").value = dados.data;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25010/discussion-between-sergio-and-diego).